# I want to prevent canceling out of save as window

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, save-as

Hi I'm very new to macros in fact below is my Frankenstein code which works great except for one little issue. I do not want the users to use the cancel button or the x button when in the save as window just like the second macro listed below my macro. I want my macro to stay the same with the exception of adding the code for  preventing users from canceling or x'ing out of the save as window.

```
Sub Auto_Open()
Dim Workbook_Name As Variant

MsgBox "Save to R drive prior to working", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Hello Ops Team"

If Dir("Z:\Provider Ops", vbDirectory) = "" Then
   MsgBox "You are not connected to the R drive"
   Exit Sub
End If
If ThisWorkbook.Name = "Triaging for Vendors.xlsm" Then Exit Sub
Workbook_Name = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("Z:Prov Ops\Triaging for Vendors")
If Workbook_Name <> False Then

   ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs _
      Filename:=Workbook_Name & ".xlsx", _
      FileFormat:=51

End If


End Sub


_______________________________________________________________


Sub PreventCancel()

Dim fPth As Object
Set fPth = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
Dim result As Variant

With fPth
    .InitialFileName = CTAPath
    .InitialFileName = CTAName & "_CAP DATA"
    .Title = "Save with your CTA file"
    .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewList
    .FilterIndex = 2
    Do
        result = .Show
    Loop While result <> True
   .Execute
End With
end sub
```

Comment: Don't. Instead, allow the user to cancel gracefully and deal suitably with the condition ... An un-cancelable modal dialog *will* bite you at some time. (E.g., what if there is no drive with write access and/or enough drive space? Or if Z: gets disconnected between your test in the first line and the saveas?)

Comment: Currently the users are saving the file/s back to the intranet causing rework for everyone. So what I need is what I have posted here under Sub Auto_Open() and some how add the feature from Sub PreventCancel(). I'm extremely new to macros and any help would be appreciated..